# Is it possible to quantify or even just suggest when someone is to blame for being tricked?

Tags: truth, belief, critical-thinking, authenticity

Is it possible to quantify or even just suggest when someone is to blame for being tricked? It is a common adage that gullible people are to blame for it, even if it is not exactly immoral to be gullible.

A good answer would bring in 'innocence' 'authenticity' 'conformism' 'trust' 'degrees of belief' etc.. I'm guessing that if it is a genuinely reasonable belief, to believe the trick, and most people would do the same in your position, then you are not to blame. But there does seem to be something **inauthentic** about that equation, to me. Maybe it has something to do with "ideology", and we are to blame when we are unable or unwilling to "think it through"

Comment: ‘“Quantify”— what would be the unit of measurement?

Comment: @MarkAndrews an example would be believing something that everyone else thinks is 2.5% possible

Comment: It is called 'victim blaming'. It's very close to saying "they deserved it".

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, thanks @WeatherVane . I am not sure I completely agree, depending on the example we're using (tricked by conspiracy theorists into thinking...) In my imagined real life case, I need to "blame" them, at least functionally and for now, else I would be in pieces (though I certainly don't think they deserved it)

Comment: It's only a "reasonable belief" in the *Age of the Self*, which lacks reason: it is emotional.

Comment: sorry I'm confused what you mean. What is "reasonable belief" @WeatherVane Do you mean that "reasonable belief" has nothing to do with blame? I completely disagree that 'reasonable belief' lacks reason. The opposite is the case!

Comment: I mean that the selfish person invents illogical reasons to justify their actions, which are driven by emotion.

Comment: Oh right @WeatherVane well I don't see it as a matter of taking sides with the deceiver or the deceived, and I don't think that is necessary

Comment: I will always take sides with the deceived.

Comment: Great @WeatherVane I hope that works out for you :)

Comment: While others delight in it. Great fodder for "reality" shows.

Comment: Yes, it's sad to think some people "take delight" in deception @WeatherVane but that's not the point. Even in my imaginary real life example, I know that they didn't "deserve" it. Yes "reality" TV, so like contemporary society and the "upvote"

Comment: This response just transfers the quantification problem. What unit is being used to measure the 2.5%?

Comment: @MarkAndrews well 'degrees of belief' are a thing in the philosophy of reasoning. I think, not just in psychiatry ha!

Comment: What unit of measurement does the philosophy of reasoning use?

Comment: a percent, i think? @MarkAndrews google "degrees of belief" if you're unfamiliar :)

Comment: Hey @WeatherVane would you defend someone from something they have been tricked into believing is good for them?